# Python Pandas: Unstack table

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

| Year | Country | Gold | Silver | Bronze |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1896 | Afghanistan | 5 | 4 | 3 |
| 1896 | Algeria | 1 | 2 | 3 |

And I want to unstack it like this:

| Year | Country | medal | no of medals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1896 | Afghanistan | Gold | 5 |
| 1896 | Afghanistan | Silver | 4 |
| 1896 | Afghanistan | Bronze | 3 |
| 1896 | Algeria | Gold | 1 |
| 1896 | Algeria | Silver | 2 |
| 1896 | Algeria | Bronze | 3 |

The idea that I have in mind is iterate over each year and create a new dataframe but I'm very stuck with that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.